# Please debug the following ORACLE SQL procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

When i run the following procedure on my oracle SQL Developer

```
create or replace
Procedure Table_Update

IS
   s_id VARCHAR2(256 byte);

   CURSOR C1 IS
   SELECT A.SR_ID
   FROM TABLE_2 B,TABLE_1 A
   WHERE A.Primary_key=B.Primary_Key;

BEGIN
loop
   open c1;
   fetch c1 into s_id;

   exit when C1%NOTFOUND ;

   update TABLE_2 set SR_ID = s_id;       

   commit;

   END LOOP;

 CLOSE C1;
END;
```

The table_1 and table_2 have similar structure.My requirement here is SR_ID from table_1 should be updated to table_2 based on the matching primary key.When i run the procedure I get the following error message

```
Connecting to the database XXX.
ORA-06511: PL/SQL: CURSOR ALREADY OPEN
ORA-06512: at "Table_Update", line 7
ORA-06512: at "Table_Update", line 13
ORA-06512: at line 2
PROCESS EXITED.
Disconnecting from the database XXX.
```

I have trying this over and over please help me

Thank you

Comment: i'm no expert but i think youe missing a `where` clause in your `update` statement.

Comment: As another point in addition to a_horse_with_no_name's excellent answer if you _were_ to do it in this way, i.e. you have a 500m row table and can't lock the entire thing it's better to use a BULK COLLECT and update on ROWID as this'll be much faster.

Answer (score 4):

As Roger already said: move the opening of the cursor outside of the loop.

But equally important: do not commit *inside* the loop either. That makes things slower, puts more stress on the database and will also close the cursor.

But more importantly: you don't need the loop at all. You can do this in a single update statement:

```
update TABLE_2 
   set SR_ID = (select a.sr_id 
                from table_1 a 
                where a.primary_key = table_2.primary_key);
```

or alternatively use a `merge` statement:

```
merge into table_2 
using table_1 a
   on (table_2.primary_key = a.primary_key)
when matched then update 
  set sr_id = a.sr_id;
```

which will be a lot faster then your cursor based approach.

Here is an SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0b810/1

Comment: +1: Or with a foreign key from table_1 to table_2 on the primary key column an update could be run against a join of the two tables.

Comment: +1 for the alternatives and insights. However, I believe he will need to update only the records he intends by using the WHERE clause. This is not clear though, OP might be confused.

Comment: @Roger: according to the question the OP wants to update all rows in table_2 to have the same values in sr_id based on the primary key. I don't think a `WHERE` clause is necessary, but it can easily be applied in both versions.

Answer (score 3):

Move `open c1;` outside of the loop, you only need to open it once.

Comment: I tried doing this  create or replace
Procedure Table_Update

IS
   s_id VARCHAR2(256 byte);

   CURSOR C1 IS
   SELECT A.SR_ID
   FROM TABLE_2 B,TABLE_1 A
   WHERE A.Primary_key=B.Primary_Key;
open c1;

BEGIN
loop
      fetch c1 into s_id;

   exit when C1%NOTFOUND ;

   update TABLE_2 set SR_ID = s_id;       

   commit;

   END LOOP;

 CLOSE C1;
END; I get a error message (11,10) Item ignored and error (11,10) 'c1' must be a type

Comment: @Sudhan and the result was? read the a_horse_with_no_name's answer.

Comment: @Sudhan Did you check a_horse_with_no_name's answer? Try moving the commit outside of the loop aswell. However, you should follow his advice, he is right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move  the `open c1;` before the `loop` 
You are opening the cursor every time you go over the loop, and you should only open the cursor once.

more info http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/