# Cursor in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I´m trying to write a CURSOR to make a task in Oracle. I´m not familiarized with cursors in Oracle. Obviously I´m doing something wrong with this. Can someone tell me what it is?.

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR c1 IS
        SELECT BADGE.EMPID
        FROM EVENTS
        INNER JOIN BADGE ON EVENTS.CARDNUM = BADGE.ID
        INNER JOIN EMP ON BADGE.EMPID = EMP.ID
        WHERE EMP.VISITOR = 0
        AND EVENTS.EVENT_TIME_UTC - 0.125 > TO_DATE('20090101 00:00:00', 'RRRRMMDD hh24:mi:ss')
        AND EVENTS.EVENT_TIME_UTC - 0.125 < TO_DATE('20120101 23:59:59', 'RRRRMMDD hh24:mi:ss');
    r1 c1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR r1 IN c1 LOOP
    UPDATE EVENTS
    SET EVENTS.EMPID = r1.EMPID
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there any error or the events are just not updated?

Comment: Why are you "*obviosuly doing something wrong*"? And besides: for this update yo don't need a cursor. You can do that with a single `UPDATE` statement. For something similar see here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16891930/330315

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also a way to do this without a cursor but this is what you want to do. The point is that you define the cursor and then loop along it. Recognize the `FOR UPDATE`

```
DECLARE 
  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT BADGE.EMPID
    FROM EVENTS
    INNER JOIN BADGE ON EVENTS.CARDNUM = BADGE.ID
    INNER JOIN EMP ON BADGE.EMPID = EMP.ID
    WHERE EMP.VISITOR = 0
    AND EVENTS.EVENT_TIME_UTC - 0.125 > TO_DATE('20090101 00:00:00', 'RRRRMMDD hh24:mi:ss')
    AND EVENTS.EVENT_TIME_UTC - 0.125 < TO_DATE('20120101 23:59:59', 'RRRRMMDD hh24:mi:ss')
    FOR UPDATE of events.empid;
BEGIN
  for l in c1 loop 
    UPDATE events
      SET empid = l.empid
      WHERE CURRENT OF c1;
  end loop;
  COMMIT;
end;
```

Comment: Be careful, "When SELECT FOR UPDATE queries multiple tables, it locks only rows whose columns appear in the FOR UPDATE clause": http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#CHDGEHBF

Comment: Thanks you!, by the way I was missing the ';' inside the loop statement

Comment: You are welcome. Now I also see it ... (about the missing semicolon ;)

Answer (score 2):

Solution without using implicit cursor (no locking issue):

```
Begin
  For X in (
        SELECT BADGE.EMPID, EVENTS.CARDNUM FROM EVENTS
        INNER JOIN BADGE ON EVENTS.CARDNUM = BADGE.ID
        INNER JOIN EMP ON BADGE.EMPID = EMP.ID
        WHERE EMP.VISITOR = 0 AND 
              EVENTS.EVENT_TIME_UTC - 0.125 > TO_DATE('20090101 00:00:00', 'RRRRMMDD hh24:mi:ss') AND 
              EVENTS.EVENT_TIME_UTC - 0.125 < TO_DATE('20120101 23:59:59', 'RRRRMMDD hh24:mi:ss')
    )
  Loop
    UPDATE EVENTS
    SET EVENTS.EMPID = X.EMPID
    WHERE EVENTS.CARDNUM = X.CARDNUM;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: That is syntactic sugar. There is still a cursor, see ""Cursor FOR LOOP statement" http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm

Comment: And you need a where clause. EMPID is being updated for all rows in the EVENTS table every time.